# rails current_model in other model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In `book/show` I want to see it's sales in each existing library without abusing the views. Can the logic be somehow be transported into the model? Current `book/show.haml`:

```
= @book.name    
- @libraries.each do |library|
      = library.sales.where(book_id: @book.id).map(&:quantity).sum
```

My idea is to add a method in `library.rb` like:

```
  def current_book_sold_by_library
    @book = Book.find(:id)
    #sales.where(book_id: @book.id).map(&:quantity).sum
    sales.map(&:quantity).sum
  end
```

But playing with this did not help. My setup:

book.rb:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

library.rb

```
class Library < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books, through: :sales
end
```

sale.rb

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :library
end
```

books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @libraries = Library.all
    @sales = @book.sales
  end
end
```

Comment: your `Library` is missing `has_many :sales`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a method with a book as a parameter to `Library` model:

```
# view
- @libraries.each do |library|
      = library.book_sold_by_library(@book)

# Library model
def book_sold_by_library(book)
  sales.where(book_id: book.id).map(&:quantity).sum
end
```